# Locating the index value of an element in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to access certain values of an array inside a dictionary using its value and not its index

For example:

```
message_dict = {
  '123456,896': 
      [[3453, 57634], [9984, 97585]], 
  '157384,899':
      [[3455, 57647], [9989, 97592]]
}
```

If I want to access 57634, I could do:

```
s = '123456,896'
message_dict[s][0][1]
```

I want to use the value of [0] instead to find 57634

I tried to specify the value directly, but syntax is invalid.

```
s = '123456,896'
i = 3453
message_dict[s]i[1]
```

This reports syntax error, but I have no idea how to specify the value, instead of the position of the value in the array.

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Use a version-specific tag at your discretion.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. If you *already have the value*, why do you need to access it in the list? In any case, the only way to get to things in a list if you don't have the index is to do a linear search (or binary search if sorted). It is still unclear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish, this seems like an X-Y problem.

Comment: `if 3453 in message_dict[s][0]` should find if 3453 is present in the first sublist

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga. I actually need the value next to it

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution:

```
next((x[1] for x in message_dict[s] if x[0] == i), None)
```

Gives `None` if it does not find a value.

Answer (score 0):

In your sublists, you want to treat the first item as a *key* and the second as a *value*. A list of pairs is not well suited for that as it will require a linear search, use a nested `dict` instead.

```
message_dict = {
  '123456,896':
      {3453: 57634, 9984: 97585},
  '157384,899':
      {3455: 57647, 9989: 97592}
}

print(message_dict['123456,896'][3453])
```

#### Output

```
57634
```

In the event you cannot change the format of `message_dict` at the source, here is how you can convert it.

```
message_dict = {
  '123456,896':
      [[3453, 57634], [9984, 97585]],
  '157384,899':
      [[3455, 57647], [9989, 97592]]
}

message_dict = {k: dict(lst) for k, lst in message_dict.items()}

print(message_dict)
```

#### Output

```
{'123456,896': {3453: 57634, 9984: 97585},
 '157384,899': {3455: 57647, 9989: 97592}}
```